# Is it possible with a Flutter app to hand off a video playing in-app to an Apple or Samsung TV?

Tags: video, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-packages

I am looking into using Flutter for a cross-platform app project, however I need functionality to hand off a video playing in-app to a TV – Apple TV, if user has an iPhone, and Samsung TV if on Android. It's similar to how the YouTube app can switch playing to a Smart TV, by clicking app in nav bar (see screenshots below).

[image: Nav bar]

[image: Popup]

Any help or advice would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is simply a question of IF flutter can do this, it most certainly can. You have access to [MethodChannels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) which allow you to create hooks directly with the native platform and create plugins for your app. A quick search on [pubdev](https://pub.dev/packages) showed that there didn't appear to be an airplay plugin already made but there was something for [chromecast](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_chromecast). However, it's noted that it is under development (doesn't look like development has continued though). This could give you a starting point on how to create a plug in with this kind of feature for yourself through MethodChannels though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adrian, and for providing all the info. Apologies for my question not being too clear. I suppose I was asking in a round-about way if there was a known package to handle the functionality, and your info has provided me with a good starting point. I was trying to weigh up if Flutter or React Native would be best for a project I'm working on, by seeing what functionality was alright available in the communities for what I need.